# Javascript/React - How does react reference document.getElementById('root') in the render method without assigning it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sorry for this obvious question perhaps, but I am learning React and really want to ask questions that puzzle me as I go through the learnings. As below, the last expression which is `document.getElementById('root')` isn't assigned to anything, so I just wondered how the render method can actually reference root? Is the render method expecting the last parameter to be the root node?

```
const element = (
  <h1>
    Hello, {formatName(user)}!
  </h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: It's passed to the function, so it doesn't need to be assigned to anything.

Comment: The `document.getElementById('root')` expression evaluates to a DOM node. It doesn't matter if you put it in a variable and pass that in or if you pass it in directly, just as you can e.g. pass `1 + 1` as an argument to a function without putting it in a variable first.

Comment: You are basically passing it as an argument. Its more like `function add(a, b){...}; add(1,2)`